# I am unable to create subtables in revtex4-2 with the following code

Tags: tables

```
 \documentclass[aps,prstper,preprint,groupedaddress]{revtex4-2}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{hyperref}
  \usepackage{makecell}
  \usepackage{graphicx,lipsum,afterpage,subfigure}
  \usepackage{supertabular}
  \usepackage{morefloats}
  \usepackage{tablefootnote}
  \usepackage{import}
  \usepackage{filecontents}
  \usepackage{multirow}
  \usepackage{booktabs}
  \usepackage{siunitx}
  \usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
  \usepackage{enumitem}
  \usepackage{soul}
  \usepackage{textcomp}
  \usepackage{threeparttablex}
  \usepackage{supertabular}
  \usepackage{morefloats}
   \usepackage{ucs}
  \usepackage{color}
  \usepackage{array}
  \usepackage{calc}
  \usepackage{multirow}
  \usepackage{hhline}
  \usepackage{ifthen}  
  \usepackage{floatrow}
  \usepackage{caption}
  \usepackage{subcaption}
  \begin{document}

\squeezetable
\begin{table}
\begin{subtable}[h]
\begin{ruledtabular}
\begin{tabular}{|l{1cm}|l{5.5cm}|l{5cm}|l{4.5cm}|}
\caption{The items of the concept inventory based on the concept of 2-D Bravais lattices\label{2d:1}}
S.No.& Description of the Question (RBT aspect)&Associated Alternative Conceptions&Distractors\\
\hline
15-16 &\textit{\textbf{Identifying and marking the Primitive Unit cell(picture based)}}(Apply conceptual knowledge)
  & unit cell, 3-D Bravais Lattices&No options as answer required marking in the given picture\\
\hline
 17-18 &\textit{\textbf{Identifying and marking the 2-D Bravais lattice(picture based)}}(Apply conceptual knowledge)
 & 3-D Bravais Lattices &No options as answer required marking in the given picture\\
 \hline
 19 & \textit{\textbf{Identifying the primitive unit cell associated with 2-D Bravais Lattices(picture based)}}
 (Analyze conceptual and factual knowledge)
  &unit cell, 3-D Bravais Lattices&\\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \end{ruledtabular}
  \end{subtable}
  \quad
  \begin{subtable}[h]
  \begin{ruledtabular}
  \begin{tabular}{|l{1cm}|l{5.5cm}|l{5cm}}
  \caption{The items of the concept inventory based on the concept of 2-D Bravais                       lattices,where the rationale for distractors is the inability of the students to differentiate between 2-D and 3-D Bravais lattices. The associated alternative      conceptions are those of unit 
   cell and 3-D Bravais lattices.\label{2d:2}}
   S.No.& Description of the Question (RBT aspect)&Distractors\\

   20 & \textit{\textbf{Mandatory features of a primitive unit cell associated with 2-D or 3-D Bravais lattices}}
  (Evaluating conceptual and factual knowledge)&\setlist{nolistsep}\begin{itemize}    [noitemsep]
                                                              \item smallest area or   smallest volume
                                                              \item one lattice point/primitive cell 
                                                               \item all lattice points are at the corner
                                                             \end{itemize}\\
 \hline
 21 & \textit{\textbf{Primitive unit cell associated with Bravais Lattice in                                     2-D}}(Evaluating conceptual and factual
  knowledge)&\setlist{nolistsep}\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
                           \item Any closed area
                           \item only polygons of smallest area
                            \item Only polygons with 2 \& 4 fold rotational symmetry
                            \end{itemize}\\
 \hline
 22 & \textit{\textbf{Symmetries possessed by Bravais Lattice in 2-D}}(Evaluating   conceptual and factual knowledge)                               
 &\setlist{nolistsep}\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
                           \item Translational Symmetry
                           \item 2, 4, 6-fold Rotational Symmetry 
                           \item Reflection Symmetry
                           \end{itemize}\\
 \hline
 23 & \textit{\textbf{Identifying equivalent Bravais lattices in 2-D (picture based)}}(Evaluating procedural knowledge)&\\                              
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
 \end{ruledtabular}
 \end{subtable}

 \end{table}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: The error message you will get from this code informs you that you can't load `subfigure` and `subcaption` in the same document. Since the former is considered deprecates, I suggest just using the latter.

Comment: Also, please clean up your preamble. Do not load packages more than once, especially not with different options.

Comment: removing subfigure is also unable to help

Comment: If you want to use the `subtable` environment from the `subcaption` package, you will have to add a width to each `subtable`. (Such as in `\begin{subtable}{0.5\textwidth}`) Also remove the `[h]`.

Comment: Also, column type such as `l` usually don't accept a width argument as you used in `l{1cm}`. Either just use `l` or `p{1cm}` instead.

Comment: Why did you place the `\caption` inside of the `tabular` environment? It should be placed outside of the `tabular` environment.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few serious errors in your code. Some of the most important ones are:

- Don't load both `subfigure` and `subcaption` -- they are not mutually compatible. The former package is deprecated; don't load it.
- The `subtable` environment takes 1 mandatory argument: the intended width. Hence, writing `\begin{subtable}[h]` is a plain and simple mistake. It should probably be `\begin{subtable}{\textwidth}`.
- The `l` column type does not take -- and has never taken -- a width argument. Hence, `l{1cm}` will cause LaTeX to crash. I don't know what your intentions are; just to get towards an acually-compilable document, I'll assume you meant `p{1cm}`, etc.
- Don't load packages more than once. Absolutely nothing good will come of that poor practice.
- Of all the packages you load, `hyperref` should be loaded *last*.
- The `\caption` and `\label` instructions belong *outside* the `tabular*  environments.

I could go on, but these are the most serious errors. Fixing these errors, deciding to employ `tabularx` evironments, omitting the `\ruledtabular` instructions (since they aren't compatible with tabularx), and setting up and using a bespoke compressed itemize-like environment called `myitemize` eventually lead to the following solution -- I will keep my fingers crossed that you like the result:

[image]

```
\documentclass[aps,prstper,%preprint,
               groupedaddress]{revtex4-2}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{booktabs}

  \usepackage{enumitem}
  \newlist{myitemize}{itemize}{1}
  \setlist[myitemize,1]{label=\textbullet, 
             wide=0pt, nosep,
             before={\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}},
             after={\end{minipage}}}

  \usepackage{subcaption}
  \captionsetup[subtable]{justification=RaggedRight,
         singlelinecheck=false,
         skip=0.333\baselineskip}

  \usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e} % new
  \newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}

  \usepackage{hyperref}  % must be loaded LAST

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t!]
\begin{subtable}{1\textwidth}
\caption{The items of the concept inventory based on the concept of \mbox{2-D} Bravais lattices}
\label{2d:1}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l LLL @{}}
\toprule
S.No.& Description of the Question (RBT aspect)
     & Associated Alternative Conceptions
     & Distractors\\
\midrule
  15--16 
  &\textit{\textbf{Identifying and marking the Primitive Unit cell (picture based)}} (Apply conceptual knowledge)
  & unit cell, 3-D Bravais Lattices
  &No options as answer required marking in the given picture\\
\addlinespace
 17--18 
  &\textit{\textbf{Identifying and marking the \mbox{2-D} Bravais lattice (picture based)}}(Apply conceptual knowledge)
  & 3-D Bravais Lattices 
  &No options as answer required marking in the given picture\\
\addlinespace
 19 & 
   \textit{\textbf{Identifying the primitive unit cell associated with \mbox{2-D} Bravais Lattices (picture based)}} (Analyze conceptual and factual knowledge)
   & unit cell, 3-D Bravais Lattices
   &\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{subtable}

\bigskip
\begin{subtable}{1\textwidth}
\caption{The items of the concept inventory based on the concept of \mbox{2-D} Bravais lattices, where the rationale for distractors is the inability of the students to differentiate between \mbox{2-D} and 3-D Bravais lattices. The associated alternative conceptions are those of unit cell and 3-D Bravais lattices.}
\label{2d:2}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l LL @{}}
\toprule
S.No.& Description of the Question (RBT aspect)
     & Distractors\\
 \midrule
 20 & \textit{\textbf{Mandatory features of a primitive unit cell associated with \mbox{2-D} or 3-D Bravais lattices}} (Evaluating conceptual and factual knowledge)
  & \begin{myitemize}
    \item smallest area or smallest volume
    \item one lattice point/primitive cell 
    \item all lattice points are at the corner
    \end{myitemize}\\
 \addlinespace
 21 & \textit{\textbf{Primitive unit cell associated with Bravais Lattice in \mbox{2-D}}} (Evaluating conceptual and factual
  knowledge)
  & \begin{myitemize}
    \item Any closed area
    \item only polygons of smallest area
    \item Only polygons with 2 \& 4 fold rotational symmetry
    \end{myitemize}\\
 \addlinespace
 22 & \textit{\textbf{Symmetries possessed by Bravais Lattice in \mbox{2-D}}} (Evaluating conceptual and factual knowledge)         
 & \begin{myitemize}
   \item Translational Symmetry
   \item 2, 4, 6-fold Rotational Symmetry 
   \item Reflection Symmetry
   \end{myitemize}\\
 \addlinespace
 23 & \textit{\textbf{Identifying equivalent Bravais lattices in \mbox{2-D} (picture based)}} (Evaluating procedural knowledge)&\\        
 \bottomrule
 \end{tabularx}
\end{subtable}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```